# How do I use GET and POST on Github using access tokens?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github-api

I am using OmniAuth to authenticate a user via Github. OmniAuth provides access tokens. Now I want to send the GET or POST request to Github. I don't want to use any gems, I want to do with Net::HTTP. I did it like this:

```
<%consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new("mshsD0jpgcYwwOEcTW5ZTA",  "V6KTqllY5jS392pj4FNFCb5EiOM8DaFzVwr9cS54XQ", { :site => "https://api.github.com", :request_token_path => '/oauth/request_token', :access_token_path => '/oauth/access_token', :authorize_path => '/oauth/authorize', :scheme => :header })%>

<%access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new(consumer,auth.token,auth.secret)%>
```

The same I previously did for Twitter worked fine but now I am getting the following error:

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::OAuth
```

Even in the same application the same thing is working for Twitter but not for Github.

I searched through Google but found nothing that helped.

Comment: can you try using top-level namespace? prepend `::` to `OAuth`, so write `::OAuth::Consumer.new` instead of `OAuth::Consumer.new`.

Comment: @shime i tried it but ended up getting "uninitialized constant OAuth" this error

Answer (score 2):

You should be using OAuth2 instead of OAuth. I'd actually recommend using [Octokit](https://github.com/pengwynn/octokit), it's easy to use and Wynn works for GitHub now so part of his job is keeping it up to date. :)

If you want to use Net::HTTP (although I can't imagine why), you can actually do that without any gems. Just put the token you got from OmniAuth in the request's "Authentication" header.

```
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'

uri = uri = URI.parse("https://api.github.com/users/username")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true

headers = { "Authentication" => "token" }
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, headers)
response = http.request(request)
response.body # => A string containing the JSON response
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're already using Omniauth and are familiar with it, I'd recommend using the omniauth-github strategy: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-github